# Why does auto.arima have much different intercept and xreg terms as lm?

Tags: r, arima, lm

I have the following

```
library(data.table)
library(forecast)
testdata<-fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deanm0000/SOexamples/main/testdata.csv")
```

If I run:

```
summary(auto.arima(testdata$y, xreg=as.matrix(testdata$xreg)))

    Series: testdata$y 
Regression with ARIMA(1,0,0) errors 

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept   xreg
      0.6783   112.4255  0.042
s.e.  0.0178    20.7612  0.021

sigma^2 = 19216:  log likelihood = -10845.79
AIC=21699.58   AICc=21699.6   BIC=21721.35

Training set error measures:
                     ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE    MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set 0.09882646 138.5005 48.80453 -19.92035 33.8495 0.9514773 0.0213895
```

If I'm not mistaken (which I obviously am) then ARIMA(1,0,0) should be the equivalent of...

```
summary(lm(y~y_lag+xreg, data=testdata))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ y_lag + xreg, data = testdata)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1464.93   -33.69   -12.31    13.75  2113.78 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 36.06855    7.00895   5.146 2.97e-07 ***
y_lag        0.67878    0.01781  38.118  < 2e-16 ***
xreg         0.01371    0.00685   2.001   0.0456 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 138.7 on 1704 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.4666,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.466 
F-statistic: 745.3 on 2 and 1704 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The ar1 term roughly equals the y_lag term as I'd expect but the intercept and xreg are way different.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have run afoul of the fact that `auto.arima()` with external regressors does *not* fit an ARIMAX model, but a regression with ARIMA errors. [Rob Hyndman explains the difference, and his rationale for this behavior of `auto.arima()` in his blog post "The ARIMAX model muddle".](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)

Essentially, the relevant comparison to your `auto.arima()` fit is not

```
summary(lm(y~y_lag+xreg, data=testdata))
```

but

```
summary(model <- lm(y~xreg, data=testdata))
```

which indeed gives similar result as the `xreg` parameter of your `auto.arima()` model:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.125e+02  9.124e+00  12.329  < 2e-16 ***
xreg        4.184e-02  9.257e-03   4.519 6.63e-06 ***
```

plus an ARIMA structure on the residuals from that OLS model:

```
summary(auto.arima(residuals(model)))
```

which gives you the same ARIMA(1,0,0) model and the same AR(1) coefficient:

```
Series: residuals(model) 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1
      0.6784
s.e.  0.0178
```